# How to use response functions in Hosted Payment Form in Chase Paymentech?

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway

I am currently working on chase payment gateway integration with php. It has very bad documentation which does not shows how to use response functions on merchant parent page. I am using hosted payment form (HPF) in chase payementech. On the merchant parent page, I have response functions and iframe which contains hosted payment form. Here I don't know how to use response functions like

```
cancelCREPayment() 
whatCVV2() 
creHandleErrors(errorCode)
creHandleDetailErrors(errorCode, gatewayCode, gatewayMessage)
completeCREPayment(transaction)
```

on the merchant parent page. I have submitted `callback_url`, `css_url` etc at the admin panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this resolved? If not, What do you have in your callback_url? chase paymenttech website documentation section provides a sample callback.html file which has the actual implementation for these methods. You can override those in your iFrame html page.

Comment: yes this issue has been resolved. I have download the callback.html from their deeveloper account and use it as callback_url and everything working fine. But i have done this before your answer ;) . By the way thanks, i accept your answer.

Comment: @ChintanPanchal Thanks for accepting! Had I seen this question before, my answer could have helped you :). This might be irrelevant but I'm wondering how you were able to capture the response information from chase in the return_url? I'm having hard time capturing it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a process what i have done, if you are using iframe for chase payment form then you must provide callback_url for response from chase payment tech. You will get this callback.html file from chase payment tech developer account. Upload callback.html file on your server and give full path to callback_url of parent iframe. That's it, and please do not make any change in callback.html. Now use those five functions like whatCVV2(), errorHandler(errorCode) etc. on your parent iframe page. Run your parent iframe page and you will see that all those functions will work. Hope this will help.

Comment: @ChintanPanchal I should have been more clear here. I'm done with callback_url stuff. **I'm only struggling to get the return_url working.** Orbital gateway documentation says that we should have a service listening for response XML from HPF at return_url. Have you configured this return_url? If so, what should I be looking for here? My code is in C#.

Comment: Venu I have been integrate chase paymentech with php. I assume that you have done process similar my above comment. Now next what i have done is when your payment is successfull [code] completeCREPayment(transaction) [/code] function will triggered. You will get all response data from chase paymentech from transaction parameter in json code. We have not provide return_url in our iframe. Using that response data i am sending ajax request to my controller and store all required data in database. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the solution. Even I've adopted a similar approach. Just wanted to know if you have done anything using the return_url as specified in the documentation. Thank you once again! :)

Comment: Hello @SantoshVemu, i am trying to integrate chase payment HPF in my website but when loading iframe it gives the following error "Store Profile is Incomplete Aborting", do you have any idea what could be the error? I have filled in all the required details in the Orbital Virtual Terminal, also i am using this in test environment. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also as an update @SantoshVemu , i have fixed the "store Profile Error" but now it says "Merchant Id missing" error. I am loading iframe with UID (using order abstraction). Documentation says to only pass UID when using order abstraction. Any help is appreciated. Thanks